# calling child_process from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having an html file with a hyperlink which calls javascript function.The javascript function has to call a batch file...this all should happen from Node.js

```
<html>
<head>
<title>sample</title>
<script src="child.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="call()">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

child.js

```
function call()
{

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
ls = spawn('append.bat');
}
```

I'm getting error like this....

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
```

any answer..pls reply...

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a server-side environment for JavaScript. To interact with it from a web page, you'll want to establish an [`http.Server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) and [use Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to communicate between.

A partial example (using a few libraries to simplify) would be:

```
// server-side
app.post('/append', function (req, res) {
    exec('appand.bat', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err || stderr.length) {
            res.send(500, arguments);
        } else {
            res.send(stdout);
        }
    });
});
```

```
// client-side
function call() {
    $.post('/append').done(function (ls) {
        console.log(ls);
    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        console.error(xhr.responseText);
    });
}
```

The libraries demonstrated are [Express](http://expressjs.com/) for server-side and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for client-side. It also uses [`child_process.exec()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) rather than `spawn()` to get `Buffer`s rather than `Stream`s.

Resources:

- [Learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/)
- [Express Guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html)
- [SO's `node.js` Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info), which includes a number of "*Tutorials, Guides and Books*" and "*Free Node.js Books and Resources*."

Answer (score 0):

You can't access Node.js from browser.

Comment: okay..without using node.js  can i call a javascript function which calls runs my batch file..

Comment: No, becouse JavaScript work on client computer. You can't access server files from there. All what You can is requesting results of file execution by AJAX.

Comment: @user2655757 Client-side JavaScript doesn't typically support executing commands or other processes. You can try Ajax, spawning the child process server-side, and report back the results.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski:hi..thanks for ur suggestion...could you please tell me with an example...

Comment: @JonathanLonowski:because i m new to nodejs

Comment: Search for AJAX in Google or make new question.